# change the user agent in python proxy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

This well known tutorial is all over the web for creating a python proxy using google app engine: http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/

If anyone has experience using it, how do you change the user agent in the script?

Answer (score 1):

GAE does not allow you to fully set User-agent header: it allows you to set the header but will always add `AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)` to the end of it.

See this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=342